# Laravel Role based authentication and view. Middleware in routes not working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

time laravel user.
i followed this step to create role-based login and view.

https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/how-to-create-multiple-role-based-authentication-and-access-control-in-laravel-application/

i believe as soon as we login, it should redirect us to respective views based on user role.
but when i login, nothing happens. it just take me to the default home page. is there anything wrong with my routes file ?

**Routes file**

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Middleware;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();


Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');


Route::group(['as'=>'admin.','prefix' => 'admin','namespace'=>'Admin','middleware'=>['auth','admin']], function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
});

Route::group(['as'=>'user.','prefix' => 'user','namespace'=>'User','middleware'=>['auth','user']], function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', [App\Http\Controllers\User\DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
});

Route::group(['as'=>'employer.','prefix' => 'employer','namespace'=>'Employer','middleware'=>['auth','employer']], function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', [App\Http\Controllers\Employer\DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
});
```

**my loginController**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */

    protected $redirectTo;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role_id == 1){
            $this->redirectTo = route('admin.dashboard');
        } elseif(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role_id == 2){
            $this->redirectTo = route('user.dashboard');
        } elseif(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role_id == 3){
            $this->redirectTo = route('employer.dashboard');
        }

        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Comment: you wouldn't be making this decision of where to redirect to in the constructor, you would do it in a different method, you don't have access to the session in the constructor

Comment: Have you registred the middleware in app/Http/Middleware/Kernel.php?

Comment: also how could a user be authenticated before they login?

Comment: yes i have the middleware registered on the kernel. and im trying to have two types of users who have different dashboard view and different profile view. im wondering how it could be done. do we need to have two different user tables, or can we seperate them with roles ?